# Prestashop module in not default checkout

Tags: stripe-payments, prestashop

I am the developer of an agency that makes modules for prestashop and one of our modules is a checkout on one page.
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/express-checkout-process/47263-one-page-checkout-fast-purchase-process.html

We already made the module compatible with the stripe payment module in older versions but we didn't really see how we could make it compatible with the latest version 3.0.5.

Actual point is generate the option with the hidden form but without the button, if we force to add the button make the call to get JSON string form make the pay but instead go to stripe only refresh the page.

A list of points to check or the module with the js unminified would help us a lot.

Thanks in advance